# How to read the value of a variable which is set inside the jquery slide toggle callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope everyone is doing fine.

I am setting a variable inside slide toggle call back function. I need to perform some action based on this variable's value.  So, I need to wait for this variable's value to be set in parent method. I think following code snippet will explain better what I am trying to do.

```
    function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal',function(){
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) 
            {
               state = "open";
            }
            else 
            {
               state = "close";
            } 
            isAnimationCompleted=true;
            return true;
    });

          while(isAnimationCompleted==false)
              {             
          //do nothing
              }
          isAnimationCompleted=false;
          var  selectedElement  =$.trim(this.textContent);
            if(state=="open" )
            {
                showHelp(selectedElement,state);
            }

        }
```

I will sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you declare 'state'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $.data() method on the object whose state you wish to keep track of. This way, the property-value combination you wish to store is associated with a particular object.

There's a great explanation of it in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/.

As far as your code goes, try this:

```
function() {
    // When the page loads, set a default value to the property,
    $("#div_you_toggle").data("open",false);

    $("#div_you_toggle").slideToggle('normal',function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) 
        {
           $(this).data("open",false);
        }
        else 
        {
           $(this).data("open",true);
        } 
        isAnimationCompleted=true;
        return true;
});

      while(isAnimationCompleted==false)
          {             
      //do nothing
          }
      isAnimationCompleted=false;
      var  selectedElement  =$.trim(this.textContent);  
        if( $("#div_you_toggle").data("open") == true )
        {
            showHelp(selectedElement,state);
        }

    }
```

There's definitely a bit of optimization that can take place, but this should introduce the basic concept.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for the help :)